# Cant open https web using Slimerjs, casperjs, phantomjs

Tags: automation, phantomjs, casperjs, slimerjs

This is first time i cant open website using headless browser such: phantomjs, slimerjs or casperjs. I just want to open website. I just create very basic script to open the website and take screenshot. but 3 (three) of them give me blank picture.

i try using:

```
--debug=true 
--ssl-protocol=TLSv1.2 (i try each of available protocol) 
--ignore-ssl-errors=true
```

Here my script:

**Slimerjs**

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
page.open("https://domain/")
    .then(function(status){
         if (status == "success") {
            page.viewportSize = { width:1024, height:768 };
            page.render('screenshot.png');
         }
         else {
             console.log("Sorry, the page is not loaded");
         }
         page.close();
         phantom.exit();
    });
```

**phantomjs**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://domain/', function() {
  page.render('screenshot.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

**casperjs**

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  viewportSize: {width: 950, height: 950}
});

casper.start('https://domain/', function() {
    this.capture('screenshot.png');
});

casper.run();
```

I even try to use screen capture service to know if they can open or not. But all of them give me nothing too.

is there i miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is not because of PhantomJS as such. The site you are checking is protected by a `F5 network protection`

https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/these-are-not-the-scrapes-youre-looking-for-session-anomalies

So its not that the page doesn't load. It is that the protection mechanism detects that PhantomJS is a bot based on checks they have implemented

[image: Page Loaded]

The easiest of fixes is to use Chrome instead of `PhantomJS`. Else it means a decent amount of investigation time

Some similar unanswered/answered question in the past

[Selenium and PhantomJS : webpage thinks Javascript is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043499/selenium-and-phantomjs-webpage-thinks-javascript-is-disabled)

[PhantomJS get no real content running on AWS EC2 CentOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097937/phantomjs-get-no-real-content-running-on-aws-ec2-centos-6)

[file_get_contents while bypassing javascript detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252208/file-get-contents-while-bypassing-javascript-detection)

[Python POST Request Not Returning HTML, Requesting JavaScript Be Enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707532/python-post-request-not-returning-html-requesting-javascript-be-enabled)

I will update this post with more details that I find. But my experience says, go with what works instead of wasting time on such sites which don't work under PhantomJS

**Update-1**

I have tried to import the browser cookies to PhantomJS and it still won't work. Which means there is some hard checks

[image: Cookies]

Comment: you really give me the clue. i will try it. btw. what do you mean about chrome. did you means [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)?

Comment: You can use that if you want or Selenium + Chrome. Selenium has binding in almost all languages

Comment: glad to spend a lot of reputation for this information. really worthed. thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue with phantomJS and the following service args resolved it:

```
--ignore-ssl-errors=true
--ssl-protocol=any
--web-security=false
--proxy-type=None
```

Can't help you with casperJS and slimerJS, and don't know exactly why this worked.